# "There were all kinds" vs "there were of all kinds"

Tags: grammar, phrases

What's is more grammatically correct?

> Once in the terminal, I started towards the nearest exit, glancing at
>   the other tourists. **There were of all kinds:** groups, husband and
>   wife, and people being waited with a sign.

Or

> Once in the terminal, I started towards the nearest exit, glancing at
>   the other tourists. **There were all kinds:** groups, husband and
>   wife, and people being waited with a sign.

Comment: Grammatically, it should be either "there were all kinds" or "they were of all kinds" (this may explain your confusion). However, [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There+were+all+kinds%2C+There+were+of+all+kinds%2C+They+were+all+kinds%2C+They+were+of+all+kinds&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that "they were of all kinds" has been steadily declining in use.

Comment: I agree with @PeterShor. Although you didn't ask this "people being waited with a sign" does not make sense. I assume you mean "people *waiting* with a name-board".

Comment: @TrevorD, since he is talking about the other tourists (i.e., not the locals), the passive is probably rather meant to refer to the people arriving, being awaited by the people holding name-boards. Additionally, “husband and wife” would be “husbands and wives”, unless you mean to say that in the whole terminal, there was only one husband and wife in sight.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet You're right. So I should write: "...people being awaited with name-boards"?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I take your point regarding *awaited*. Of course, that raises another - albeit pedantic - point. The sentence initially implies that the "kinds" are mutually exclusive, but either of the first two kinds could fall within the third kind! Also, I did consider suggesting "couples* rather than "husbands and wives", primarily as being more concise - but, unless he studied 'rings on fingers', he also could not of course know whether they were married!

Comment: I quite agree. And within groups there could be couples or husbands and wives, as well, so they are not really mutually exclusive groups at all. Moreover, you cannot tell just by looking at someone in an airport if they are a tourist or not. If it were me, I would recast the sentence as, “Once in the terminal, I started towards the nearest exist, glancing at the other tourists—couples, groups, people looking for their names on name-boards” (_vel sim_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There were of all kinds** is never correct.  **There** is a Dummy Pronoun here and needs an object (like Predicate Nominative).

Also you should say **husbands and wives** as we are talking about different groups.

**Waited** when used as passive needs the Dependent Preposition *on* or *for*.

Without major edits I submit this version:

*Once in the terminal, I started towards the nearest exit, glancing at the other tourists. There were all kinds: groups, husbands and wives, and people being waited for with signs.*